visual studio code (Python file in terminal does not work)
pressing run does not work on mac. Let say I want to run the code, it will not be executed. I tried reinstalling python and visual studio but I could't resolve the problem. if anyone can give me solution to this problem . and thank you

if you enter `python script_name.py' in the terminal does it run? Does VScode indicate that a Python Interpreter has been selected?  Do you have the Python extension for VSCode installed?

Please mention exactly what you're typing/pressing to run the python script.
